# Need 'e-novative DocBook Environment (eDE)' Install Files

Tags: docbook

The 'e-novative DocBook Environment' is a brain dead simple DocBook toolchain built specifically for the Win32 platform by a company called e-novative GmbH. The company appears to have went out of business. Their website [http://www.e-novative.de] is dead and apparently the install files for their DocBook environment have somehow managed to disappear from the face of the internet.

I have searched and searched [and searched some more] and every single download link I come across ultimately points back to the company's dead website. I cannot believe that there are no other copies of the software.

If anyone can either provide me the install file or point me to a place that has them I would be eternally grateful. So much so that I would offer up my first born child in payment. Okay, that's not true but I would be very very appreciative!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've uploaded the version that I have to this location:
http://ifile.it/5wbgz7n/docbook_ede_130.zip

I believe it's 1.3.0.

**Update:** The file is apparently also [available on the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20060421134908/http://www.e-novative.info/software/ede/ede_download.php).

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but there's also a port for Unix available: http://www.foxplanet.de/docbook/

Answer (score 3):

Start your search at the wayback machine